# Split a list of objects into a list and a grouping, based on criteria

Tags: c#, linq

I'd like to know what's the most efficient and correct way to do the following:

1. We're given a list of objects. Here's an exampler object:

   ```
   public class Search
   {
       public string ColumnName {get; set;}
       public string Value {get; set;}
   }
   ```
2. One of the object's properties can hold only two "types" of string values: A dot-seperated value, and a non-dot-seperated value. 
   For example:

   ```
   List<Search> searches = new List<Search> 
   {
       new Search(){ColumnName = "field1", Value = "1"},
       new Search(){ColumnName = "field2", Value = "2"},
       new Search(){ColumnName = "joined1.field3", Value = "2"},
       new Search(){ColumnName = "joined2.field4", Value = "3"},
       new Search(){ColumnName = "joined1.field2", Value = "4"},
   };
   ```
3. We need to split the given list by checking the potentially-dot-seperated property value, so that those that are non-dot-seperated are put into a list, and those that are dot-seperated are put into a grouping by the property value.

   The above list should be split into the following structure (Please run the following snippet to display the example):

   ```html
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
     <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
       <meta name="Generator" content="LINQ to XML, baby!" />
     <style type='text/css'>
   body
   {
    margin: 0.3em 0.3em 0.4em 0.5em;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 80%;
    background: white;
   }

   p, pre
   {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family: Verdana;
   }

   table
   {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 2px solid #17b;
    border-top: 1px;
    margin: 0.3em 0.2em;
   }

   table.limit
   {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #c31;
   }

   td, th
   {
    vertical-align: top;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    padding: 0.1em 0.2em;
    margin: 0;
   }

   th
   {
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #ddd;
    border: 1px solid #777;
    font-family: tahoma;
    font-size:90%;
    font-weight: bold;
   }

   th.member
   {
    padding: 0.1em 0.2em 0.1em 0.2em;
   }

   td.typeheader
   {
    font-family: tahoma;
    font-size: 90%;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #17b;
    color: white;
    padding: 0 0.2em 0.1em 0.1em;
   }

   td.n { text-align: right }

   a:link.typeheader, a:visited.typeheader
   {
    font-family: tahoma;
    font-size: 90%;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #17b;
    color: white;
    float:left;
   }

   span.typeglyph
   {
    font-family: webdings;
    padding: 0 0.2em 0 0;
    margin: 0;
   }

   table.group
   {
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
   }

   td.group
   {
    border: none;
    padding: 0 0.1em;
   }

   div.spacer
   {
    margin: 0.6em 0;
   }

   table.headingpresenter
   {
    border: none;
    border-left: 3px dotted #1a5;
    margin: 1em 0em 1.2em 0.15em;
   }

   th.headingpresenter
   {
    font-family: Arial;
    border: none;
    padding: 0 0 0.2em 0.5em;
    background-color: white;
    color: green;
    font-size: 110%;        
   }

   td.headingpresenter
   {
    border: none;
    padding: 0 0 0 0.6em;
   }

   td.summary
   { 
    background-color: #def;
    color: #024;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    padding: 0 0.1em 0.1em 0.1em;
   }

   td.columntotal
   {
    font-family: Tahoma;
    background-color: #eee;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #17b;
    font-size:90%;
    text-align:right;
   }

   span.graphbar
   {
    background: #17b;
    color: #17b;
    margin-left: -2px;
    margin-right: -2px;
   }

   a:link.graphcolumn, a:visited.graphcolumn
   {
    color: #17b;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 110%;
    letter-spacing: -0.4em; 
    margin-left: 0.3em;
   }

   i { color: green; }

   em { color: red; }

   span.highlight { background: #ff8; }
     </style>

     <script language='JavaScript' type='text/javascript'>

         function toggle(id)
         {
           table = document.getElementById(id);
           if (table == null) return false;
           updown = document.getElementById(id + 'ud');
           if (updown == null) return false;
           expand = updown.innerText == '6';
           updown.innerText = expand ? '5' : '6';
           table.style.borderBottom = expand ? '2px solid' : 'dashed 2px';
           elements = table.rows;
           if (elements.length == 0 || elements.length == 1) return false;
           for (i = 1; i != elements.length; i++)
             if (elements[i].id.substring(0,3) != 'sum')
               elements[i].style.display = expand ? 'block' : 'none';
           return false;
         }
       
     </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   <div>
     <div class="spacer">
       <table id="t2">
         <tr>
           <td class="typeheader" colspan="2">
             <a href="" class="typeheader" onclick="return toggle('t2');">
               <span class="typeglyph" id="t2ud">5</span>List&lt;Search&gt; (2 items)</a>
             <a href="" class="typeheader" style="float:right; padding-left:2pt; margin-left:4pt" onclick="return window.external.CustomClick('1',false);">
               <span style="font-family: webdings; margin-top:1.2pt" id="t2ud">4</span>
             </a>
           </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <th title="System.String">ColumnName</th>
           <th title="System.String">Value</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>field1</td>
           <td>1</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>field2</td>
           <td>2</td>
         </tr>
       </table>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div>
     <div class="spacer">
       <table id="t6">
         <tr>
           <td class="typeheader" colspan="1">
             <a href="" class="typeheader" onclick="return toggle('t6');">
               <span class="typeglyph" id="t6ud">5</span>List&lt;IGrouping&lt;String,Search&gt;&gt; (2 items)</a>
             <a href="" class="typeheader" style="float:right; padding-left:2pt; margin-left:4pt" onclick="return window.external.CustomClick('5',false);">
               <span style="font-family: webdings; margin-top:1.2pt" id="t6ud">4</span>
             </a>
           </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>
             <table class="group">
               <tr>
                 <td class="group">
                   <i>Key=</i>
                 </td>
                 <td class="group">joined1</td>
               </tr>
             </table>
             <table id="t7">
               <tr>
                 <td class="typeheader" colspan="2">
                   <a href="" class="typeheader" onclick="return toggle('t7');">
                     <span class="typeglyph" id="t7ud">5</span>IGrouping&lt;String,Search&gt; (2 items)</a>
                   <a href="" class="typeheader" style="float:right; padding-left:2pt; margin-left:4pt" onclick="return window.external.CustomClick('6',false);">
                     <span style="font-family: webdings; margin-top:1.2pt" id="t7ud">4</span>
                   </a>
                 </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                 <th title="System.String">ColumnName</th>
                 <th title="System.String">Value</th>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                 <td>joined1.field3</td>
                 <td>2</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                 <td>joined1.field2</td>
                 <td>4</td>
               </tr>
             </table>
           </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>
             <table class="group">
               <tr>
                 <td class="group">
                   <i>Key=</i>
                 </td>
                 <td class="group">joined2</td>
               </tr>
             </table>
             <table id="t8">
               <tr>
                 <td class="typeheader" colspan="2">
                   <a href="" class="typeheader" onclick="return toggle('t8');">
                     <span class="typeglyph" id="t8ud">5</span>IGrouping&lt;String,Search&gt; (1 item)</a>
                   <a href="" class="typeheader" style="float:right; padding-left:2pt; margin-left:4pt" onclick="return window.external.CustomClick('7',false);">
                     <span style="font-family: webdings; margin-top:1.2pt" id="t8ud">4</span>
                   </a>
                 </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                 <th title="System.String">ColumnName</th>
                 <th title="System.String">Value</th>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                 <td>joined2.field4</td>
                 <td>3</td>
               </tr>
             </table>
           </td>
         </tr>
       </table>
     </div>
   </div>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```
4. What I currently have:

   ```
   var dotSeperatedOrNotGroups = searches.GroupBy(s => s.ColumnName.Contains('.')).ToList();
   var nonDotSeperatedList = dotSeperatedOrNotGroups
                              .Where(s => s.Key == false)
                              .SelectMany(s=>s)
                              .ToList();
   var dotSeperatedGroups = dotSeperatedOrNotGroups
                              .Where(s => s.Key == true)
                              .SelectMany(g=>g)
                              .GroupBy(g => g.ColumnName.Split('.')[0])
                              .ToList();
   ```

   How can it be improved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If two categories is all you need then it's easier to use `ToLookup` instead of  `GroupBy`. With it you'll be able to select the *group* by a `bool` value:

```
var nonDotSeperatedList = dotSeperatedOrNotGroups[false]...
var dotSeperatedGroups = dotSeperatedOrNotGroups[true]...
```

You could also use a `Dictionar<bool, T>` but an `ILookup<T>` has the advantage that its indexer will return an empty collection instead of throwing an exception if a key does not exist.

Now you can also rename the `dotSeperatedOrNotGroups` to `dotSeperatedGroups` so the usage is even easier to read with the `bool`s

```
var nonDotSeperatedList = dotSeperatedGroups[false]...
var dotSeperatedGroups = dotSeperatedGroups[true]...
```

But remember to not call `ToList` anymore so that you can work with `ILookup<T>` and not a list:

```
var dotSeperatedGroups = searches.ToLookup(s => s.ColumnName.Contains('.'));
```

In your example calling `ToList` is unnecessary too. The group is already created and calling `ToList` just enumerates it again.

Comment: Thanks. I can see how I can do it with `ILookup<bool, Search>`, but I'm not sure, how can I use it with `ILookup<T>` (`T`, I guess, being `Search`)?

Answer (score 1):

I would bring dot into the class.  An have ctor for cleaner new.

```
public class Search
{
    public string ColumnName {get; set;}
    public bool? ColumnNameDot 
    {
       if(String.InullOrEmpty) 
       { 
           return null;
       }
       else 
       {
           return ColumnName.Contains('.');
       }
    }
    public string Value {get; set;}
    public Search (string columnName, string value)
    {
        ColumnName = columnName;
        Value = value;
    }
}
```